# the value of form:select didn't get selected from controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i set the value of `form:select` but in the result it didn't get selected.

My controller:

```
contactBF.setNom(contact.getNom());
contactBF.setQualite("130");
model.put("contact", contactBF);
model.put("qualities", [...]);
```

My jsp page:

```
<form:form id="contactform" modelAttribute="contact" action="">

     <form:input path="nom"  type="text"/>
     <form:select  path="qualite">
       <option value=""> ... </option>
       <c:forEach items="${qualities}" var="qualite" >                      
           <option value="${qualite.id}" >${qualite.nom}</option>
       </c:forEach>
     </form:select> 

</form>
```

the `form:input` get fill with the right value and `form:select` is loaded with all item but the right value is not selected !

i know this solution work:

```
<option value="${qualite.id}" ${(qualite.id == contact.qualite) ? 'selected' : ''}>${qualite.nom}</option>
```

But it wil be a lot of test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i replace :

```
   <c:forEach items="${qualities}" var="qualite" >                      
       <option value="${qualite.id}" >${qualite.nom}</option>
   </c:forEach>
```

By :

```
<form:options  items="${qualiteList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="nom" />
```

And it's work ;)